# Java: appear in the beginning guide

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

The below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int e, result;
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
        result=1;
        e=i;
        while(e>0){
            result*=2;
            e--;            

        }
        System.out.println("2 to the "+i+" power is "+result);          
    }
}
```

I have a few questions with the code above:

1. Isn't result overwritten to 1 in the for loop?  How did the power is really being calculated?
2. Why do you need e-- in the while loop?

Comment: Your code is computing `2` to power of `i`, where `i`, the exponent, can vary between 0 and 9, the bounds o the `for` loop.  Just step through your code to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

One, the `while` loop is inside the `for` loop and performs the multiplication many many times. And, two because it is being used to count down to `0` from `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + (int) Math.pow(2, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk you throught iterations

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int e, result;
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    result=1;
    e=i;
    while(e>0){
        result*=2;
        e--;            

    }
    System.out.println("2 to the "+i+" power is "+result);          
}
}
```

i = 0

```
e=0
result = 1;
```

i=1

```
e=1
result=2*1
```

i=2

```
e=2
result= 1*2*2
```

i=3

```
e=3
result= 1 *2 *2 *2
```

i=4

```
 e=4
 result = 1 *2 *2 *2 *2
```

...

Answer (score 0):

1. No isn't, because it's done after the for iteration result is shown (System.ou.print..). Setting result to 1 is **only** useful for first 'for iteration' (i=0 and while loop is skiped). Power is computed by the 'while loop'. result is set to 1 for i=0 by this code and well computed for other values of i.
2. For the 'while loop' end reason. Without this, the 'while loop' will be infinite. With e-- instruction the 'while loop' is done exactly i times.